# Removing control / special characters from log file

Tags: bash, sed, tcl

I have a log file captured by tclsh which captures all the backspace characters (ctrl-H, shows up as "^H") and color-setting sequences (eg. ^[[32m .... ^[[0m ).  What is an efficient way to remove them?

**^[...m**

This one is easy since, I can just do "sed -i /^[.*m//g" to remove them

**^H**

Right now I have "sed -i s/.^H//", which "applies" a backspace, but I have to keep looping this until there are no more backspaces.

```
while [ logfile == `grep -l ^H logfile` ]; do sed -i s/.^H// logfile ; done;
```

"sed -i s/.^H//g" doesn't work because it would match consecutive backspaces.  This process takes 11 mins for my log file with ~6k lines, which is too long.

Any better ways to remove the backspace?

Answer (score 2):

You could always write a simple pipeline command to implement the backspace stripping, something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 10240

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int c ;
    int buf[BUFFERSIZE] ;
    int pos = 0 ;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case '\b':
        {
            if (pos > 0)
                pos-- ;
            break ;
        }
        case '\n':
        {
            int i ;
            for (i = 0; i < pos; ++i)
                putchar(buf[i]) ;
            putchar('\n') ;
            pos = 0 ;
            break ;
        }
        default:
        {
            buf[pos++] = c ;
            break ;
        }
        }
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

I've only given the code a minimal test and you may need to adjust the buffer sze depending on how big your lines our.  It might be an idea to assert that pos is < BUFERSSIZE after pos++ just to be safe!

Alternatively you could maybe implement something similar with the Tcl code that captures the log file in the first place; but without knowing how that works it's a bit hard to say.

Comment: +1, although you should make `BUFFERSIZE` a round number. (I usually use 4096.)

Comment: it looks like that should work, although I was hoping for a quick linux command.

Answer (score 1):

Your could try:

```
sed -i s/[^^H]^H//g
```

This might or might not work in one go, but should at least be faster than one at a time as you seem to be doing now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That is an improvement for lines that have more than one sequence of backspaces, but if I have a string of 10 backspaces, I'll still have to loop 10 times.

Comment: for some reason, that seem to ran forever.  Not sure why [^^H] doesn't seem to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that “sed” doesn't just do substitutions? The commands of a sed script have to be on separate lines though (or at least they do on the version of sed I've got on this machine).

```
sed -i bak 's/^[[^^]]*m//g
: again
s/[^^H]^H//g
t again' logfile
```

The `:` sets up a label (`again` in this case) and `t` branches to a label if any substitutions have been performed (since the start/last branch). Wrapping those round a suitable `s` gets the substitution applied until it can't any more.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put it out here, I ended up doing this.  It's not a pretty solution and not as flexible as Jackson's answer but does what I need in my particular case.  I basically use the inner loop to generate the match string for sed.

```
# "Applies" up to 10 consecutive backspaces
for i in {10..1}; do
  match=""
  for j in `seq 1 $i`; do
    match=".${match}^H"
  done;

  # Can't put quotes around s//g or else backspaces are evaluated
  sed -i s/${match}//g ${file-to-process}
done;
```